# Support for 'webworker' in higher version of android

Tags: html

I Tested html5 feature 'webworker' on safari 5.1, iphone 4 as well as android mobile with OS 2.3. The feature works perfectly

But there is no support for 'webworker' in higher versions of android OS (browser)

If anyone know the answers please reply.

Comment: The [caniuse table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) and [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers#Browser_Compatibility) both indicate that Android stocked browser doesn't support WebWorker; but with Android >=4, you can have Chrome For Android. Plus Opera Mobile is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

[the answer is no you can see all compatibility of web worker here on can i use](http://caniuse.com/webworkers)